# Why do we need garbage collection if we want to have functions as first class citizens?

Tags: garbage-collection

I saw this question and couldn't really understand why GC is a necessity in such cases.

I am guessing it has something to do with closures, because I  think we would need to save the context of non local variables somewhere and the stack may be no good for that (can't really figure why).

Am I even close?

Comment: Maybe this question is out of context generally you need no GC to have first class functions, but having GC would make things easier.

Comment: You “saw this question” or actually *asked* this question, e.g. right here? Normally, such a question would arise when you see a claim that GC was needed for true FP, but then, you should add a link to the original statement. As without additional context, I can only second Lee, the implied claim is just wrong.

Comment: @Holger I saw this exact question asked. No rephrasing, no extra context.

Comment: Where? And did this source question contain a source for the implied assumption that GC was necessary?